# How to temporarily modify / delete records in cascade without affecting database?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a 3-level database, tables such as:

```
class GrandParent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'grandparent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    field0 = Column(Float)

    parents = relationship("Parent", back_populates="parent", cascade="all, delete-orphan")


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    field0 = Column(Float)

    parent_id = Column("parent", Integer, ForeignKey("grandparent.id"))
    parent = relationship("GrandParent", back_populates="parents")

    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent", cascade="all, delete-orphan")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    field0 = Column(Float)

    parent_id = Column("parent", Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id"))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

I stored a record for `GrandParent` that holds N records of `Parent`, each handling M records of `Child`. I need to modify `GrandParent` instance structure such that it is convenient to erase all its children and grand-children and rebuild the tree. I have to perform these modifications *in memory*, before letting the user save (persist) changes to the database.

I tried:

```
for parent in grand_parent.children:
    for child in parent.children:
        session.delete(child)
    session.delete(parent)

# Other code here to add children/ gran-children from scratch to the grand_parent instance
```

This gives strange behaviour: the new instances are replicated along with the old ones attached to `grand_parent`.

So I tried force in-class-object deletion:

```
for parent in grand_parent.children:
    parent.children.clear()
grand_parent.children.clear()
```

Does not work either, with the same result (even if I join the two methods and delete both class-object and from session). How to handle this?

Comment: Once `session.delete` has been called on an entity it will be present in the session's `deleted` attribute, so you can check that. However it will remain in the session and any relationship collections etc until the session is committed.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong: you're saying that, once a record has been loaded from the database, it's not possible to in-memory (or, maybe better, in session) delete it without affecting the underlying db data? Am I wrong?

Comment: I am saying that between deleting in the session and committing, the programmer is responsible for handling "deleted" records in whatever way the application requires.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What's the way to access only **living** objects, filtering out all the deleted ones?

Comment: If you don't mind calling `session.flush()` you can use the techniques in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60691513/5320906).  If you don't want to flush the session, `obj in session.deleted` will work.  See the docs on [State Management](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#state-management).

Comment: Great! I ignored the difference between `flush` and `commit`. Now it's clearer! In particular, `obj in session.deleted` is a valid way, though a bit pedantic. I can surely use `flush` for all the changes required by the user along with `rollback` in case of changes discard or `commit` in case of changes acceptance. Thank you very much for the help!